# How do I go back to original 12.04 kernel?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, default, remastersys

I wanted to make a custom ISO, so I spent the whole day setting up a partition with all the applications and little tweaks that I thought would be comfortable for 12.04 32-bit.

I'm using Remastersys to do so, and when I went to do so, it said everything went fine, but when I checked under `/etc/remastersys`, I couldn't find it.

Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place? Anyways, I saw in an article that Remastersys doesn't support the Linux kernel from after the original 12.04 release.

How do I return my kernel to the original version it was in the default 12.04 without having to reinstall the partition and all the applications all over again?

Answer (score 0):

Install synaptic package manager, open it and search for "linux-image". Uninstall all images but the one with the lowest version number and click "Apply". You're done.